# CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting a very opaque error message - CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 0.

This Dockerfile worked well previously, but I think there is a problem with it in Visual Studio 2022.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Domain/Domain.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Domain"
RUN dotnet build "Domain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Domain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Domain.dll"]
```

Here is some output contained in the error message.

```
Error   CTC1014 Docker command failed with exit code 0.
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:ba397cfd6a85fea7615e57b5f632e17dfe4ac20a6c2b07dfdcd8c7a587e883e6
#1 transferring dockerfile: 32B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:bfedc4c930f4484872cee371d877847209702c992fc338f315c6a2ebe3dc8641
#2 transferring context: 35B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine
#3 sha256:9337467cb8fe7867559fc863b311aabee0d106a98140d42d52ac6117f7521c70
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine
#4 sha256:092644c54b62ff663a37e497fd57dae090e3e2dfcf4d8a2e244da3f243a8e7ba
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
#5 sha256:dd536a017cb8f843354fc922eca5f2a24794bce1f7aefdae696c44de0399c8eb
#5 CACHED

#6 exporting to image
#6 sha256:e8c613e07b0b7ff33893b694f7759a10d42e180f2b4dc349fb57dc6b71dcab00
#6 exporting layers done
#6 writing image sha256:bdf53eed611b6b0e2edb0c20902378cb6cb2683ac8401acf88f51951a248ca48 
done
#6 naming to docker.io/library/domain:dev done
#6 DONE 0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how 
to fix them
```

It seems only two of the Docker commands are completing. Is there something wrong with this Dockerfile? Why is this project not running in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was that the Container Tools Nuget package needed updating for VS 2022, but in the end there were more issues and I ended up upgrading to .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Container Tools Nuget Package did the trick for me as well on VS 2022.  Thanks